# In model function to initial model fail

Tags: ios, swift, model

Get model info fail. see my breckpoint line in `initFormListModelWithDic`:
Model initial method is this:

```
import UIKit

class FormListModel: NSObject {

    var total:String = "0.00"
    var commission:String = "0.00"
    var year:String = ""
    var month:String = ""

class func initFormListModelWithDic(_ dic: [String:Any]) -> FormListModel {

    let model:FormListModel = FormListModel.init()

    model.total = UtilSwift.getStrFromAny(dic["total"] ?? "")
    model.year = UtilSwift.getStrFromAny(dic["year"] ?? "")
    model.month = UtilSwift.getStrFromAny(dic["month"] ?? "")
    model.commission = UtilSwift.getStrFromAny(dic["commission"] ?? "")

    return model  // breakpoint here, po model.total -> "0.00"  here I lldb the information. see below.
    }
}
```

In the `lldb`:

```
(lldb) po model.year
""


(lldb) po dic
▿ 3 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - .0 : "total"
    - .1 : 0.00
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    - .0 : "year"
    - .1 : 2016
  ▿ 2 : 2 elements
    - .0 : "month"
    - .1 : 12


(lldb) po dic["total"]
▿ Optional<Any>
```

In the `UtilSwift`:

```
class func getStrFromAny(_ any:Any) -> String {

    let ret = any as? String ?? String(any as? String ?? "")

    return ret!
}
```

Where is the mistaken？ I cannot find out.

Comment: And what would you expect the result to be?  Everything seems fine.

Comment: @Losiowaty I have edit my question, see the breakpoint line and the lldb.

Comment: - .0 : "total"  - .1 : 0.00, output is fine. `po model.total -> "0.00"`

Comment: @Losiowaty sorry to confuse, po `mode.year`  -> `""`

Comment: My guess is that `dic["year"]` isn't a String. Can you please verify?

Comment: @EricAya - Would you suggest him to declare variable in exact datatype as in response, e.g: `total` look` like a _double_, `year` and `month` are _integers_?

Comment: @EricAya the UtilSwift*s method get any to string

Comment: i will try and reply